# 'foreach' Function In Mathmatics

Tags: matrices

In computer programming there is a tool called `for each` where a function can be ran for each item in a matrix.

Is there an equivalent to this in pure math syntax?

**Additions for clarification:**

I want to know if there are other ways to express this $B = [f(A,1),...,f(A,n)]$ where $A$ and $B$ are single dimension matrices and $n$ is the total number of items in Matrix $A$

I have a function $f(A,i)$ and I have to preface it with the statement. "For each item in A solve the formula where $i$ is the index of the resulting matrix."

So when I want my new matrix $B$ I have to do $f(A,1)$, $f(A,2)$, ..., $f(A,n)$

The final matrix would look like this
$[f(A,1),f(A,2), ..., f(A,n)]$ (or a transposed version of that)

**ANSWER:** This question was closed, however the answer is in the comments of the question.

Comment: In mathematics, we don't "run" functions. Could you give an explicit example of what you want to describe?

Comment: @Théophile the language is definitely different. The two answers are worded as though they are absolute truths, whereas the wording of my question and examples are not. I will attempt to state my example in a way that mirrors them.

Comment: If I understand your clarification, I don't think you need further language to explain that each component of $B$ is related to $A$; you simply write it more or less as you did: Given an $n\times1$ matrix $A$ and the function $f(A,i)$, define the $n\times1$ matrix $B$ as follows: $$B(A) = [f(A,1)\ f(A,2)\ \cdots\ f(A,n)]^T$$
Notice how it is more efficient to include $n$ in the description of $A$ rather than later saying "where $n$ is the total number ...".

Comment: @Théophile I was thinking about this over the weekend and it would be more accurately written like this $B(A)=[f(A_{1}) f(A_{2})... f(A_{n})]$ but, truely? there is no simpler form to write this?

Comment: Oh, I see: you're just referring to the $i$th element of the vector $A$? In that case, assuming you're working with real numbers: "Given $\mathbf a \in \Bbb R^n$, define $\mathbf b \in \Bbb R^n$ by $b_i = f(a_i)$."

Comment: @Théophile Are the 'Given' and 'Define' statements necessary?

Comment: No, certainly not: they're not formal commands that "do" anything like in computer programming. I was simply trying to write a complete sentence. The shortest way to say what you want is the very last part, i.e.,:
$$b_i = f(a_i)$$

Comment: For something so simple to be so difficult. Thank you. This is exactly what I was wanting.

Comment: You're welcome! One last thing: it would be good to specify for which $i$ that statement holds, so to be more complete, I'd write one of the following (take your pick): $$b_i = f(a_i), \quad \forall i \in [1,n]$$ or $$b_i = f(a_i), \quad 1 \le i \le n$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a branch of mathematics that deals with logic. The symbol you’re looking for expresses [universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification).

If you want to express that for each (sometimes also called “for all”) $x$, you have that $y$ is true, then you notate $$(\forall x) \quad y$$ or something equivalent. There are many, *many* different ways to notate implication with $\forall$. Many people use arrows or parentheses, especially since $:$ is used for “such that.”

This can get more complicated, too. For example, it’s true that the square of every real number is nonnegative: $$(\forall x\in\Bbb{R}) \quad x^2\ge0$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a set $S$, which has the property that all matricies inside of it has $\det = 0$.

Then you can easily write like this:

$S=\{M\in M_{n\times n}|\det(M)=0\}$

This is read as, $S$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matricies $M$, such that $\det(M)=0$

You can think of it as, "each" matrix has $\det = 0$